# Drupal adding some sort of hash on end of clean URL?

Tags: uri

The site is working normally otherwise, but junk like this: #.ULQf0OOe90s is added onto the end of every URL.

Any ideas why this might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems very similar to this topic in Wordpress:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/random-hashtag-strings-added-to-url-in-firefox

Did you had the "Share this" module installed?

Comment: Hmmm, I am using the Addthis plugin/module

Comment: I am pretty sure it belongs to the [AddThis click tracking](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381252-click-tracking). You should be able to disable the click tracking and still use AddThis without the URL fragment.

Comment: Thanks guys, I changed this <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script> to false and it solved the problem